# ls command thinks directory is file

Tags: linux, terminal, ls

I have a directory `brothers` which contains files `John.txt` and `Max.txt`.  I can cd into and out of directory `brothers` with no problems.  However, when I'm in `brothers` superdirectory (one level up) and I use the command `ls -l` it prints the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 128 Jun 26 13:59 brothers -> filePathHere
```

As you can see from the first letter of the above output, the command `ls -l` thinks that `brothers` is a file rather than a directory.  Shouldn't the first letter be a `d` (it shows a `d` for all of my other directories)?  How can I fix this?

Comment: Lots of misinformation above.  "l" represents a soft link.  Hard links don't show up any differently than normal files in the "ls" command.  And, soft links to a directory can be made by any user.

Comment: @gnometorule `l` does not mean hard link, it just means link. Any user can create a soft link to a directory.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I was careless, and will delete the comment; just adding this to not let your correction hang in the air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the man page of `ls`:

> l = The entry is a symbolic link, and either the -N flag was specified
>   or the symbolic link did not point to an existing file.

And for further reference `d` denotes a directory and `-` denotes an ordinary file.

Answer (score 1):

'brothers' is a special type of file called a symbolic link.  It's similar (though there are some differences) to a shortcut in Windows.  when you `cd` to 'brothers', you're actually going to 'filePathHere'.

Comment: what Nosrettap is seeing is a soft link and not a hard link. Symbolic links or soft links, unlike hard links, points to filename, not file data itself.